# UWP app WACK test fails & outputs debug irrespective of chosen settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I am trying to create a package of my UWP app and put it through a WACK test. 
Windows App Certification Kit - Test Results is FAIL. I think it's because VS2015 is outputting a debug build irrespective of the settings i've chosen. 
Has anyone come across this problem before? 
Is visual studio ignoring my settings, or does my project include a library that's not going to pass WACK?

[image: Configuration]
'Release' is selected both in the build menu and in Output Package dialogue.

[image: Libraries]
JSON.net and EF7 only, both are UWP compatiable. Tasks and DataAccess are a background task and a class library.

> File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\f0679d56-bdc0-4305-837e-16b5560c7c41_1.0.14.0_x86__ade4xr40r36he\coreclr.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
>   File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\f0679d56-bdc0-4305-837e-16b5560c7c41_1.0.14.0_x86__ade4xr40r36he\dbgshim.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
>   File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\f0679d56-bdc0-4305-837e-16b5560c7c41_1.0.14.0_x86__ade4xr40r36he\mscordaccore.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
>   File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\f0679d56-bdc0-4305-837e-16b5560c7c41_1.0.14.0_x86__ade4xr40r36he\mscordbi.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.

[image]

Comment: what do you have defined in project properties/build and configuration manager?

Answer (score 1):

i also have the same issue and it is caused due to `EntityFreamework.Commands` reference. When you building the code for store package or release mode just remove all references of `EntityFramework.commands` by uninstalling from nuget. 
that should help to get rid of those errors. for more information please go [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/245). let me know how it went.. all the best.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using VS2015 preview 2 and everything is building with it just fine. I get no errors in the WACK. 
Microsoft just decided to release .net native a year before it could actually compile things properly.